# pushing new changes to GitHub after deleting hidden .git directory

Tags: git, github, .git-folder

I've removed the hidden .git file from the project folder as I wanted to test pushing to a github directory from a new machine, can anyone list below the proper steps?

This is the message I got from the terminal:

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again
```

That is for reference only so please don't try to fix this error just focus on the main steps only with the assumption I went inside the project directory and removed the hidden .git file.

Possibly answer as follows:

1. git pull
2. git merge
3. GIT PUSH so on...

Comment: `.git` contains the repository. Without this folder, you can't do anything. You have to initialize a new repository or clone again.

Comment: @tkausl so step 1)  clone.  or step 1)  git init? 
btw i did git init  git commit and git push to origin -u origin and address 
that's why i would like to see a list of steps if posible

Comment: If you have deleted the .git directory you can't get the message you have shown because you aren't in a Git repository anymore.

Comment: @mkrieger1 that message appeared to me after i tried pushing to Github meaning i used the git init command, that's why i said ( please don't try to fix this error)  but just try to give me the proper steps so i don't encounter such an error in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

- Delete the new .git folder
- clone the repo from git to your system
- copy and paste the .git from newly downloaded repo to your existing project
- Delete the downloaded repo